# How to load application using u-boot for an ARM Processor

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, processor

I am currently writing an application (very simple and basic hello world program in C) on a 64-bit Linux machine. I've compiled by application using an ARM embedded gcc toolchain by Linero to cross compile the application onto my board. For info, I'm using a FOX G20 V board with an ATMEL AT91SAM9G20 processor.

So, I've compiled my application using: `arm-none-eabi-gcc` while adding a few options that allow me to use the standard C functions (such as printf etc.). This compiled successfully and I was able to obtain the binary file, ready to load onto my board.

The next step therefore was to compile and build U-Boot to be able to load my application onto my board. I followed the compilation and build using

> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC} distclean
>
> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC} at91sam9g20ek_mmc_config
>
> make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CC}

by specifying to the compiler where exactly the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` path lies.
This compiled and was built successfully.

Now that I have my application binary file, and my U-Boot built and ready for loading, how do I actually load my application onto the board? I've tried to follow tutorials online but have been rather unsuccessful. Ideally, I would like to load my application on the SD Card of my board. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `return` is not a function.

Comment: Yes, ok, thank you. I mean the printf function then.

Comment: Let me fix that for you! ;-)

Comment: Thank you :). Do you have any possible advice/help concerning the question?

Comment: You're skipping/missing a boot program. U-Boot typically executes in DRAM, which would be memory that is external to the SoC. So you typically need to a program before U-Boot to initialize the DRAM controller, and then load U-Boot (which ends up a 3rd-stage boot program). The ARM SoC typically has a (built-in) ROM program to load this 2nd-stage loader (into internal SRAM). You could use U-Boot's SPL, or use Atmel's AT91Bootstrap. Note that you could configure & use AT91Bootstrap to load a baremetal program instead of U-Boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do not you start from the default hello word program given in u-boot source code only..

Its at `u-boot/examples/hello_world.c`

Enable it in compilation using its config file and try to load it. 
This will shows some ways. http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootStandalone

Comment: I've seen this tutorial and and I'm not able to do a `tftp` transfer. Also, what do you mean by "enable it in compilation using its config file"? Finally, when I compile an application, am I meant to load the executable or the binary file?